# How can I allocate a boolean array for RenderScript output?

Tags: android, c, renderscript

I'm trying to optimize my image processing code because for large images it takes a long time to process using Java.

I did some method profiling with DDMS and found this method eating up nearly 50% of cpu time:

```
private int getBrightness(int color) {
    // returns an int from 0-255 where zero is pure black and 255 is pure white,
    // weighted to correspond to perceived brightness
    // http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx
    int red = Color.red(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int brightness = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt((0.241 * red * red) + (0.691 * green * green) + (0.068 * blue * blue)));
    return brightness;
}
```

Specifically, the calls to Math.sqrt() and Math.round() are the real culprits here. This combined with the fact that this is computed serially when it could be done in parallel means my processing takes way too long.

Someone pointed me towards RenderScript. I decided it sounds perfect for what I'm trying to do. I know C++ but not C, and I'm having a hard time with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically, at processing time I don't need to know the actual brightness of each pixel, just whether it is above or below the threshold (which won't change during the lifetime of this object). So I can simply create an array of boolean values that tell me if the pixel is >= the threshold (true) or < the threshold (false). So I can move the brightness computation to the C code in the renderscript.

I'd like to directly return a true or false value into the ouput Allocation. This is what I'm having trouble with.

Here is my Renderscript C code:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.mushroomhouse.pixelbomb)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

int threshold = 160;

bool __attribute__((kernel)) generate(uchar4 in) {
    int r = (int) (255*sqrt((float)((0.241 * in.r * in.r) + (0.691 * in.g * in.g) + (0.068 * in.b * in.b))));
    return (r>threshold);
}
```

And here is the relevant code from my processing class:

```
(Member variables)
...
RenderScript myRS;
ScriptC_brightness_map script;
Allocation allocIn, allocOut;
boolean[][] truthMap;

(Public Constructor) {
    ...
    myRS = RenderScript.create(context);
    script = new ScriptC_brightness_map(myRS);    
}

(Initialization before processing is done)
...
truthMap = new boolean[width][height];
allocIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(myRS, product);
allocOut = ????
script.set_threshold(brightnessValue);
script.forEach_generate(allocIn, allocOut);
...

(Processing)
```

So,

1. How do i initialize allocOut, I need an allocation that i can copy to boolean[][].
2. Can i immediately copy allocOut to my boolean[][] truthMap or do I need to use some sort of callback? I've read that RenderScript is asynchronous, so will this cause problems?

The processing is done via an IntentService in the background so waiting for RenderScript won't be a problem.

Another option would be to have the Renderscript simply return the computed brightness values and I could do the comparison in the Java code. Might be a little slower but if it's the only way this would work, I can live with that. But I'm still completely lost as to how to do such a thing. There's plenty of tutorials on how to have both inAlloc and outAlloc be a bitmap of the same dimensions but not really anything I can find about different output allocations.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things.

First of all, keep in mind that according to the C99 spec, when you have floating-point constants in a function with no qualifier (eg, 0.53 or something like that), they are technically double precision. In other words, they're **slow**. Unless you know you need double precision, you probably don't need it, and for simple image processing like this, you definitely don't need it. Just add an f to the constant (eg, 0.53f) and it'll be handled as a single-precision value.

You do need an Allocation for allocOut. The easiest way to do that is with a Type.Builder. Build a 2D Type with `Element.BOOLEAN` with the same dimensions as your bitmap. To copy it back, you want to copy to a `boolean[]`, not a `boolean[][]`, and index into that with `truthMap[y * width + x]`. IIRC, you can use `copyTo` to get data into that `boolean[]` so long as its size is width * height of the allocation.

If you can't copy (and I honestly forget, I haven't dealt with Java booleans in a long time), you could switch to a byte[] and `Element.U8` as the RS element and write 0 or 1 instead of false/true.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about floats. I changed my approach and I'm very close to having it working. I did what I suggested at the end of my question, having the RenderScript return an int foreach and copy that into an int[] brightnessMap. Now I'm running into a runtime error: Dimension mismatch between input and output parameters. 

`allocOut = Allocation.createSized(myRS, Element.I32(myRS), brightnessMap.length);`

So I suppose I have to make a 2d allocation. Looking into that now. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: yeah, the input and output allocations have to have the same dimensions (x and y), but I think a 2D Allocation is allowed to copy into a 1D Java array.